# cgal compilation, surface reconstruction

Tags: c++, cgal, geometry-surface, scikit-image

I have recently installed cgal library and for the moment I am newbie with this library, which seems to me not easy to use. Unfortunately, I am running out of the time and I am looking for quick and existing solutions.

In my project, I need to reconstruct a triangulated mesh of a surface given by a zeros of a level-set function (distance function). The level-set is evaluated in the center of a 3D Cartesian mesh. I have already used skimage library in python, where a standard marching cube algorithm is used to mesh the surface with triangulate meshes . Visually, this library seems to work fine but when I computed the curvatures using some discrete differential geometry formulas (like Gauss-bonnet), the curvatures are not enough accurates. For this reason, I would like to try cgal library.
I ask if you could orient me toward an existing and simple examples, where a surface is reconstructed from a 3D level-set matrix using cgal library.

I have also some issues related to a compilation some cgal examples. I have tried to compile the example in :

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3_2poisson_reconstruction_example_8cpp-example.html

The compilation command that I use:

```
g++ -frounding-math -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -lCGAL -lmpfr -lboost_thread -lgmp poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp
```

But I get these errors:

```
poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp:65:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<CGAL::Epick>::compute_implicit_function()’
     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
                                               ^
poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp:65:47: note: candidates are:
In file included from poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp:17:0:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:372:8: note: template<class SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, class Visitor> bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, Visitor, double, double) [with SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d = SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d; Visitor = Visitor; Gt = CGAL::Epick]
   bool compute_implicit_function(
        ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:372:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp:65:47: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
                                               ^
In file included from poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp:17:0:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:525:8: note: template<class SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d> bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, bool) [with SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d = SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d; Gt = CGAL::Epick]
   bool compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d solver, bool smoother_hole_filling = false)
        ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:525:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp:65:47: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: I guess you need to install Eigen and add -DCGAL_USE_EIGEN to your compile line.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still gives me the same errors

Comment: According to the [doc](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/classCGAL_1_1Poisson__reconstruction__function.html#a5b01f27b151690449f33c9eb421f7c97) it is `CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED`

Comment: Thank you, It works but now I have another error, it seems to me that I need to link eigen library ???  THAT is THE ERROR: /usr/bin/ld: ./poisson_reconstruction_example.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line